# C# Complex inside of a list - Aforge

Tags: c#, arrays, list, aforge

I'm trying to use Aforge.Math to do this
I want a list and then inside a complex list...
For example List[1,2] have inside a Complex List of 5 numbers and so for the other positions too:

```
  List<int>[,] Alist = new List<int>[20,20];
  AForge.Math.Complex[] input = new AForge.Math.Complex[5];
  for(int a=1; a<=5; a++){
        for(int b=1; b<=20; b++){
              for(int c=1; c<=20; c++){ //all 'for's must be in this order
                    input[a].Re = a * b; //for example
                    input[a].I = 0.0;
                    Alist[b,c] = input; //ERROR
              }
        }
  }
```

Error:`Cannot implicity convert type 'AForge.Math.Complex[] to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'`

If I use Array instead of List gives the same error.
How can i do this? Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on your code;

```
  List<int>[,] Alist = new List<int>[20,20];
```

// OK, Alist is a 2D array of List. Every member of the 2D array must be a List.

```
  AForge.Math.Complex[] input = new AForge.Math.Complex[5];
```

// OK, input is a 1D array of AForge.Math.Complex

```
  for(int a=1; a<=5; a++){
        for(int b=1; b<=20; b++){
              for(int c=1; c<=20; c++){ //all 'for's must be in this order
                    input[a].Re = a * b; //for example
                    input[a].I = 0.0;
                    Alist[b,c] = input; //ERROR
```

// Hmm. Every member of Alist must be a List, as you've said it's a 2D array of List. So setting member [b, c] to a 1D array of AForge.Math.Complex is an error

```
              }
        }
  }
```

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, but I hope you understand what is not working now.

Comment: oh ok I understand, thank you! But now, how can I create a 2D list with a 1D complex inside?
    List<int>[,] Alist = new AForge.Math.Complex[20,20];  
This is not possible :p

Comment: Actually, why do you want it to ne a List<int>[,]? Where do the ints come in? Why not a 2D array of AForge.Math.Complex?

Comment: You're confusing an Array with a List. You don't need a List. You need: AForge.Math.Complex[,] Alist = new AForge.Math.Complex[20,20]

Comment: But how can i do it?  I need the position information [for(int b=1; b<=20; b++)  and  for(int c=1; c<=20; c++)] and a list of another information (for(int a=1; a<=5; a++))] I can't have just a AForge.Math.Complex[,]

Comment: I really can't see why not? What extra data do you need?

Comment: for example:
AForge.Math.Complex[,] Alist = new AForge.Math.Complex[20, 20];
AForge.Math.Complex[] input = new AForge.Math.Complex[5];
input[1].Re = 2; input[2].Re = 5;
Alist[1, 1] = input; //Error

And if they were simple lists I could do that .. I'm not very familiar with Aforge, sorry

Comment: Change the first line of you code from List<int> to AForge.Math.Complex and leave everything else as it is. You've chopped out the array indeces in this latest comment: don't.

Comment: With:AForge.Math.Complex[,] Alist = new AForge.Math.Complex[20, 20];
AForge.Math.Complex[] input = new AForge.Math.Complex[5]; 
I get: Alist[b,c] = input; //error again 
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AForge.Math.Complex[]' to 'Aforge.Math.Comple'

Comment: Just look at your code. Step through it with a debugger. Thing about what each assignment is doing: this instance of type A is being assigned to an instance which is a type B, can that be done? Read the error message and believe what it is telling you.